# Memory Models and Singletons in C++

Tags: c++, memory, singleton, sequential, consistency

in a lecture about parallel programming, we were told this old thread-safe pattern for singletons in C++ should not be used anymore:

```
class A {
 public:
  static A* instance() {
    if (!m_instance) {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_instance_mutex);
      if (!m_instance)
        m_instance = new A();
    }
    return m_instance;
   }
 private:
  A()
  static A* m_instance;
  static std::mutex m_instance_mutex;
 }
```

This is because there is no guarantee that without a clean memory model, the following steps have no clear order:
1. Allocate memory for A
2. Initialize Object A
3. make m_instance point towards that memory

E.g. there could be reordering from 2 after 3: m_instance could already point there, but there is no valid object. Another thread could now come and see an non-zero pointer, but operates on invalid data.

This is why we should use Meyer's Singleton that places memory fences.

But I am not sure why there is no guarantee for the order of these steps: I thought C++ and Java utilized the Sequential Consistency memory model, which disallows any kind of StoreLoad/LoadStore/StoreStore/LoadLoad reordering. Even with Total Store Order, that allows StoreLoad reordering, why could 2 and 3 be swapped?

Comment: Singletons are an *anti*-pattern. Don't use them in the first place.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue whether singletons are a pattern or anti-pattern (and at least according to the GoF, they are - yes I know they apologized for it later on). I try to understand C++'s default memory consistency model

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I think this then applies:

from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

> ...8) The side effect (modification of the left argument) of the built-in assignment operator and of all built-in compound assignment operators is sequenced after the value computation (but not the side effects) of both left and right arguments, and is sequenced before the value computation of the assignment expression (that is, before returning the reference to the modified object)..."

If *"side effects"* includes the calling constructor;  then the compiler could store the address of the raw memory in `m_instance` before calling the constructor.  A second thread would then think `m_instance` is completely constructed.

The following is thread safe since C++11:

```
class A
{
  private:
    A() {};

  public:
    A& get_instance()
    {
      static A instance;
      return instance;
    }
};
```

> Variables declared at block scope with the specifier static have static storage duration but are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration...
>
> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once...

from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this is more or less Meyer's Singleton I mentioned. My question is more why the other one isn't thread safe (in order to understand C++'s memory consistency model)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, can use atomic operations like atomic_store to make sure the step 2 and 3 order? step1 maybe no need just make m_instance initialize as NULL.